# How to speed up a http c server on larger payload?

Tags: c, http, server

I have a `http c server` I got from https://rosettacode.org. I tried to test it for typical web page sizes on text payloads of 1MB to 3MB. However, it seems that as payload increases, the server performance decreases in terms of the maximum possible request/s it can handle.

What I am expecting is that the network will be the one that should be saturated since the cpu just hands in the memory address of the response to the network.

How do I speed up the performance of this server when handling larger payloads? Consider only 1 cpu core scenario.

Relevant part of the code is written below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <err.h>

char response[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n"
"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Bye-bye baby bye-bye</title>"
"<style>body { background-color: #111 }"
"h1 { font-size:4cm; text-align: center; color: black;"
" text-shadow: 0 0 2mm red}</style></head>"
"<body><h1>Goodbye, world!</h1></body></html>\r\n";

int main()
{
  int one = 1, client_fd;
  struct sockaddr_in svr_addr, cli_addr;
  socklen_t sin_len = sizeof(cli_addr);

  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sock < 0)
    err(1, "can't open socket");

  setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(int));

  int port = 8080;
  svr_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  svr_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  svr_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &svr_addr, sizeof(svr_addr)) == -1) {
    close(sock);
    err(1, "Can't bind");
  }

  listen(sock, 5);
  while (1) {
    client_fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &sin_len);
    printf("got connection\n");

    if (client_fd == -1) {
      perror("Can't accept");
      continue;
    }

    write(client_fd, response, sizeof(response) - 1); /*-1:'\0'*/
    close(client_fd);
  }
}
```

Update:

The part on the `response[]` can be updated by a 1MB-3MB plaintext to serve as the payload.

Tests was conducted on localhost. Keepalive state was not change on small or bigger payloads.

Comment: who serves 1-3 mb web pages?

Comment: I don't understand how this code is relevant to the question. It serves nothing except for a predefined response.

Comment: *since the cpu just hands in the address of the response to the network* -- what do you think the network is?

Comment: Updated the question according you your queries.

Comment: What does it mean when you say that performance decreases? Sending more data means copying more data and executing more code. This will be slower. Plus if you are running both server and a client on the same machine, there is no network activity - it all goes through intermediate memory buffer. And server will be blocked on `write` until client reads some data, which means context switching between threads is required to achieve this - taking more cpu time.

Comment: I am expecting this must be done automatically through DMA. So there are almost only few times the cpu does its jobs. 1. for telling the network hardware to get this data in the memory, then. 2. for being notified that the network does its job.

Comment: Your performance is going to be terrible because your response claims HTTP 1.1 compliance when your code doesn't comply with HTTP 1.1 nor does it behave in ways the client expects. The most obvious problem is that it begins sending a reply before the client has even sent a query. The client might even detect the closure of the connection before it sends the first byte of its query. Do you expect the connection to be kept alive or not? That's the default in HTTP 1.1, you don't say otherwise, but you don't support it. How's the client supposed to make sense of that?

Comment: @DominicGuana OS will first have to copy data to the socket buffer before starting any network activity. In theory if there is large amount of data being written in a blocking manner, OS could send data from that memory directly, but this can screw up signal handling, so I don't think any OS does this. The large the payload - the larger chunk of memory you are copying on each `write`.

Comment: @Ivan I think you are right, even though the CPU is not doing much of its job, the transfer of chunks from memory to network through DMA PCI BUS is just as fast as it can get which is typically in speed of 500MB/s. I think I am getting almost exactly what I should be. Darn! I hope there are still optimizations out there.

Comment: first optimization:  do not stay on the main thread of the server when communicating with the client as this results in serializing all the I/O.  Rather use a thread (or multiple threads)  Suggest using a `thread pool`  Then the main thread is available to handle initial contacts from a client and the threads (in the thread pool) handle all communication with the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a side note, your code does nothing related to HTTP, so it's not really a "http server", but that's not what the question is about.

Your question is that the performance is slow. And the answer is simple - the call to `write()` is blocking. It doesn't merely "hand in the memory address of the response to the network" - it also waits until it's delivered! So the way this code is written, you're really just processing one request at a time. No wonder your requests-per-second drop as the payload increases.

What you need is "asynchronous" (also known as "non-blocking") processing - your "reads" and "writes" should return immediately, not waiting until the data is delivered. This way you can service multiple sockets in parallel, even without multiple threads. The downside however is that juggling them all will become pretty complicated. But if you do it right, you'll saturate your CPU and/or network to it's fullest.

The details about this are pretty lengthy and I won't repeat them here again. Googling for "linux non blocking socket example" seems to bring up many good results, as well as the famous [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) covers all the important points in a very nice way. Read that!

Comment: Yes, yes, that link you sent would be very valuable in fixing it!